# How to change color and size of pie chart's default labels in Google Image Charts?

Tags: google-visualization, pie-chart

Is it possible to change color and font size of default pie labels (in this simple example: "Hello" and "World") in Google Image Charts API? I've searched the documentation but I can't figure out how to do it...

Example code:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World&chxs=0,008000,16&chxt=x

You define chxt=x
Then you set the color using chxs in this format

```
chxs=0,{color_code},{font-size}
```